# how can i autormatically call a folder to my web address

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to understand what to write with htaccess on how to call a folder to my web address such as when i have www.domain.com i want to rewrite to htaccess that it will automatically call my index page from my home just like this www.domain.com/home without typing my web address in full when i type in my web address like this: www.domain.com it will automatically go to www.domain.com/home

I know this is possible but i have forgotten how to do it i did it before but i didn't save the file.

Thanks, appreciate for any help.

This is what i have tried so far

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please apply basic grammar to your text. This means: A phrase starts with a capital and ends with a full stop. Besides that, I am not sure what the actual question is. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: @Sumurai8, this my grammar is very simple to understand unless you are not an English speaking person

Comment: A giant line of text without any form of interpunction is just lazyness. There is no language I am aware of that has no form of interpunction. It gives me a headache reading it; it requires me to read and re-read, and even then it is not really clear what you mean. These questions are very low quality, and should be downvoted and closed. They are worthless to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.padalogis\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.padalogis.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?padalogis\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home/ [L,R]
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, but i want the /home/ directory to still remain on it, because the code you provided to me to the index.php and not from the /home/ like example after i place the code it open the index www.domain.com instead of www.domain.com/home so i want something that can open the /home/ directory itself and not only the index.php

Comment: Sorry don't understand your comment. This rule above will internally open `/home/` folder. If there is an `/home/index.php` file then its content will be shown otherwise it will just list directory content of `/home/`. Pls clarify what different behavior you want.

Comment: no i don't want something that will open the   /home/index.php   only    www.domain.com/home   what i mean is that when you type in     www.domain.com   with type the it in full like this    www.domain.com/home   just   www.domain.com   like this it will open  www.domain.com/home  which is the htaccess will complete it to get the user where the index is because the index of the package is inside the   /home/

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to understand your long comment. I have answered hundreds of questions on .htaccess but somehow I am unable to understand your requirements clearly. If you can tell what URL you want to show in your browser and for that what URL should load the content probably that would be better.

Comment: this is simple i don't know why you found it hard to understand me, i want a www.domain.com to open like this www.domain.com/home when someone type only the domain name which is www.domain.com it will open like this www.domain.com/home, you see it will automatically insert the /home at the end of it without any further files like index.php.

Comment: remember in a web designing when you create a folder and inside the folder you create a file called index.php on a server when you only type in the folder with out index.php remember it will index the index.php and open the index.php for you without opening the folder and also the file just like this /folder/index.php no when it open only the folder the server understands what index.php is so it will open the index.php base on a file inside the folder like this /folder the index.php is only on the file it doesn't have to open it in full like /folder/index.php it will just open this way /folder

Comment: i don't know why this is so hard to understand i have done this before but just that i didn't save the htaccess code and i couldn't remember how i did it

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.